# Problems deploying application on JBoss 7 Final

Tags: web-applications, jboss, jboss7.x

I am trying to migrate my business application which is running on JBoss 5.1 GA to JBoss 7. I am confronted with different errors and I can't find a way to fix this. So let's start with my configuration:

standalone.xml:

```
         <datasource jndi-name="java:/SSIS2DSDev" pool-name="SSIS2DSDev" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
              <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx:SSISD1</connection-url>
              <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
              <driver>ojdbc5.jar</driver>

              <security>
                  <user-name>user</user-name>
                  <password>password</password>
              </security>

              <validation>
                  <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                  <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                  <useFastFail>false</useFastFail>
              </validation>
              <statement>
                  <prepared-statement-cache-size>100</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                  <share-prepared-statements/>
              </statement>
            </datasource>
            <driver name="ojdbc5.jar" module="com.oracle">
              <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
```

Please note that the connection url is the same like in JBoss 5.1. I have removed the IP, the user and the password.

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

        <!-- SSIS2 Development Database --> 
        <persistence-unit name="SSIS2">
            <jta-data-source>java:/SSIS2DSDev</jta-data-source>
            <properties>
                <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
                <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" />
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>   
    </persistence>
```

server.log after JBoss start:

```
    Calling C:\java\jboss-as-web-7.0.0.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: C:\java\jboss-as-web-7.0.0.Final

  JAVA: C:\java\jse\bin\java

  JAVA_OPTS: -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -server

===============================================================================

09:57:03,342 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.0.1.GA
09:57:03,739 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.0.GA
09:57:03,798 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBoss AS 7.0.0.Final "Lightning" starting
09:57:05,009 INFO  [org.jboss.as] creating http management service using network interface (management) port (9990) securePort (-1)
09:57:05,020 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] Removing bootstrap log handlers
09:57:05,095 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (Controller Boot Thread) Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 11.2)
09:57:05,108 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.subsystem] (Controller Boot Thread) Activating Infinispan subsystem.
09:57:05,233 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (Controller Boot Thread) Activating Naming Subsystem
09:57:05,249 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (Controller Boot Thread) Activating OSGi Subsystem
09:57:05,272 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (Controller Boot Thread) Activating Security Subsystem
09:57:05,332 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) Starting Naming Service
09:57:05,361 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBoss Remoting version 3.2.0.Beta2
09:57:05,428 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO Version 3.0.0.Beta3
09:57:05,450 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.0.Beta3
09:57:05,725 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener] (MSC service thread 1-2) The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\java\jse\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:
\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\java\apache-maven\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Win
dows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
09:57:05,782 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ee] (Controller Boot Thread) Activating EE subsystem
09:57:06,036 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
09:57:06,098 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-4) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080
09:57:06,136 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jmx.JMXConnectorService] (MSC service thread 1-1) Starting remote JMX connector
09:57:06,557 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) Bound data source [java:/SSIS2DSDev]
09:57:06,512 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-1) Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.0.CR2)
09:57:06,692 INFO  [org.jboss.as.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\java\jboss-as-web-7.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments
09:57:06,731 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBoss AS 7.0.0.Final "Lightning" started in 3743ms - Started 91 of 146 services (55 services are passive or on-demand)
```

--> data source has been bound, jdbc driver found.

```
Using "deploy-only" server in Eclipse Indigo, I publish my war file to the server and I get the following error:

    09:57:06,803 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) Starting deployment of "SSIS2_1.war"
09:57:07,188 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/C:/java/jboss-as-web-7.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/SSIS2_1.war/WEB-INF/lib/mail.jar" does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
09:57:07,258 INFO  [org.jboss.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-2) read persistence.xml for SSIS2
09:57:07,819 INFO  [org.jboss.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-2) starting Persistence Unit Service 'SSIS2_1.war#SSIS2'
09:57:08,029 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (MSC service thread 1-2) Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final
09:57:08,056 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH00412:Hibernate [WORKING]
09:57:08,058 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH00206:hibernate.properties not found
09:57:08,060 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH00021:Bytecode provider name : javassist
09:57:08,078 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH00204:Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: SSIS2
        ...]
09:57:08,179 WARN  [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH00194:Package not found or wo package-info.java: com.sicap.ssis2.controller.ServerManagement
09:57:08,180 WARN  [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH00194:Package not found or wo package-info.java: com.sicap.ssis2.servlets
09:57:08,181 WARN  [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH00194:Package not found or wo package-info.java: com.sicap.ssis2.testing
09:57:08,182 WARN  [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH00194:Package not found or wo package-info.java: com.sicap.ssis2.controller.CustomerManagement
09:57:08,184 WARN  [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH00194:Package not found or wo package-info.java: com.sicap.ssis2.listener
09:57:08,186 WARN  [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH00194:Package not found or wo package-info.java: com.sicap.ssis2.controller.PackageManagement
09:57:08,188 WARN  [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH00194:Package not found or wo package-info.java: com.sicap.ssis2.controller.UserManagement
09:57:08,189 WARN  [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH00194:Package not found or wo package-info.java: com.sicap.ssis2.model
09:57:08,191 WARN  [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH00194:Package not found or wo package-info.java: com.sicap.ssis2.controller.SolutionManagement
09:57:08,193 WARN  [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH00194:Package not found or wo package-info.java: com.sicap.ssis2.controller.LicenseManagement
09:57:08,376 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."SSIS2_1.war#SSIS2": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."SSIS2_1.war#SSIS2": Failed to start service
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1786)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ClearTCCLTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2291)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_10]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_10]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_10]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: SSIS2] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:903)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:879)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitService.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitService.java:170)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitService.start(PersistenceUnitService.java:80)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1765)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Associations marked as mappedBy must not define database mappings like @JoinTable or @JoinColumn: com.sicap.ssis2.model.Role.users
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bind(CollectionBinder.java:485)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1939)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:768)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:684)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3381)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3335)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1319)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1709)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:77)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:894)
        ... 9 more

09:57:08,655 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) Deployment of "SSIS2_1.war" was rolled back with failure message {"Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"SSIS2_1.war#SSIS2\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"SSIS2_
1.war#SSIS2\": Failed to start service"},"Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"SSIS2_1.war\".component.\"com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.AddUser\".START missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.AddUser/em\" ]","jboss.d
eployment.unit.\"SSIS2_1.war\".component.\"com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.EditServerSpecification\".START missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.EditServerSpecification/em\" ]","jboss.deployment.unit.\"SSIS2_1.war\".component.\"com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.Ge
tAllEmailaddresses\".START missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.GetAllEmailaddresses/em\" ]","jboss.deployment.unit.\"SSIS2_1.war\".component.\"com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.EditSupplier\".START missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_
1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.EditSupplier/em\" ]","jboss.deployment.unit.\"SSIS2_1.war\".component.\"com.sicap.ssis2.testing.DeletePackagesFromPerformanceTest\".START missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.testing.DeletePackagesFromPerformanceTest/em\" ]
","jboss.deployment.unit.\"SSIS2_1.war\".component.\"com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.AddFavorite\".START missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.AddFavorite/em\" ]","jboss.deployment.unit.\"SSIS2_1.war\".component.\"com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.EditChangesFile\
".START missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.EditChangesFile/em\" ]","jboss.deployment.unit.\"SSIS2_1.war\".component.\"com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.AddTestStatus\".START missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2
.servlets.AddTestStatus/em\" ]","jboss.deployment.unit.\"SSIS2_1.war\".component.\"com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.EditRegion\".START missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.EditRegion/em\" ]","jboss.deployment.unit.\"SSIS2_1.war\".component.\"com.sicap.ssi
s2.servlets.GetInsertedPackagesStatistic\".START missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.GetInsertedPackagesStatistic/em\" ]","jboss.deployment.unit.\"SSIS2_1.war\".component.\"com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.UsernameValidation\".START missing [ jboss.namin
g.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.UsernameValidation/em\" ]","jboss.deployment.unit.\"SSIS2_1.war\".component.\"com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.EditRecommendedValue\".START missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.EditRecom
mendedValue/em\" ]","jboss.deployment.unit.\"SSIS2_1.war\".jndiDependencyService missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.AddFavorite/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.EditServer/em\", jboss.naming.c
ontext.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.RemoveFavorite/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.DownloadCSV/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.AddLicense/em\", jboss.naming.conte
xt.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.EditRegion/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.testing.DeletePackagesFromPerformanceTest/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.UsernameValidation/em\
", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.listener.MySessionListener/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.ChangeUserActivation/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.EditCu
stomer/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.DeletePackage/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.DeleteCustomer/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.Delete
License/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.DeleteSolution/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.DeletePackageFromServer/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.serv
lets.EditUser/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.AddSupplier/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.AddItemToServer/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.
AddCustomer/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.AddPackage/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.ResetPassword/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.Delet
eSupplier/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.DeleteLicenseFromServer/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.DeleteItem/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servle
ts.DeleteServerSpecification/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.testing.PackagePerformanceTest/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.DeleteInstallation/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"e
nv/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.EditSupplier/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.EditLicense/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.AddUser/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.si
cap.ssis2.servlets.RequestPackage/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.EditRecommendedValue/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.AddKernelToSolution/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_
1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.SendPackageSummary/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.DeleteRecommendedValue/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.EditChangesFile/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.modul
e.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.AddRecommendedValue/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.AddRegion/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.EditSolutionKernel/em\", jboss.naming.context.jav
a.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.AddTestStatus/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.GetAllEmailaddresses/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.AddSolutionKernel/em\", jboss.naming.
context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.AddServer/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.listener.ContextListener/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.EditPackage/em\", jboss.naming.cont
ext.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.DeleteRegion/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.AddItem/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.DeleteChangesFile/em\", jboss.naming.context
.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.AddSolution/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.ChangeProfile/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.DeleteUser/em\", jboss.naming.context.java
.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.EditServerSpecification/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.ForgotUsername/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.DeleteSolutionKernel/em\", jboss.n
aming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.AddInstallation/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.DeleteServer/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.SSIS2_1.SSIS2_1.\"env/com.sicap.ssis2.servlets.ChangeLicenseActivation/em
\", [Error is repeating for every class in the app]
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Thanks a lot,
doonot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem in my model.

Wrong Role.java:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
@JoinColumn(name = "userId")
public Collection<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}
```

Correct Role.java:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "MapUserUserRole", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "roleId") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "userId") })
public Collection<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}
```

After fixing this, the application deployed and the database updated itself.